# How to improve the subplots part with a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
# dataframe with 8 columns using pandas dictionary method:

 df = DataFrame({'x1':[10.,8,13,9,11,14,6,4,12,7,5],
         'y1':[8.04,6.95,7.58,8.81,8.33,9.96,7.24,4.26,10.84,4.82,5.68],

         'x2':[10.,8,13,9,11,14,6,4,12,7,5],
         'y2':[9.14,8.14,8.74,8.77,9.26,8.1,6.13,3.1,9.13,7.26,4.74],

         'x3':[10.,8,13,9,11,14,6,4,12,7,5],
         'y3':[7.46,6.77,12.74,7.11,7.81,8.84,6.08,5.39,8.15,6.42,5.73],

         'x4':[8.,8,8,8,8,8,8,19,8,8,8],
         'y4':[6.58,5.76,7.71,8.84,8.47,7.04,5.25,12.5,5.56,7.91,6.89]})

# creating subplots:
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)

df.plot(x='x1', y='y1', ax=axes[0,0], kind='scatter')
df.plot(x='x2', y='y2', ax=axes[0,1], kind='scatter')
df.plot(x='x3', y='y3', ax=axes[1,0], kind='scatter')
df.plot(x='x4', y='y4', ax=axes[1,1], kind='scatter')
```

Also, I would be glad to see if there are better approaches for sub-plotting in `pandas` or `matplotlib` to get the same result  but more efficient than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use pd.wide_to_long to reshape your dataframe and use subplot parameter in pandas plot.

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
df_out = pd.wide_to_long(df1,['x','y'],'index','values',sep='',suffix='.')\
  .set_index(['x'],append=True)\
  .unstack(1)\
  .reset_index('index',drop=True)

df_out.plot(subplots=True, marker='o', linestyle='none', layout=(2,2));
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses a for loop to create the same plots. `ax.flatten()` helps to simplify this approach by allowing you to reference the subplots as `ax[n]` rather than `ax[x,y]`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax = ax.flatten()
for n in range(4):
    col_num = str(n+1)
    ax[n].scatter(df['x'+col_num], df['y'+col_num])
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]